# Find android device's direction/position relative to user?

Tags: android

Is it possible to find whether my device is pointing towards the sky or ahead by the way the user holds it?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation by which I can know whether this is possible or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible. What you're looking for is "orientation sensing." I found what looks like a good [introduction to using orientation sensing here.](http://www.workingfromhere.com/blog/2009/03/30/orientation-sensor-tips-in-android/)

Also, here's the [Android documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can detect - the orientation of the device.
Use gyroscope API for this.

But please be aware - gyroscope doesn't present on all android devices.

Comment: Random curiosity, do you know what devices don't have the gyroscope? It would seem to me that any of them running 2.1+ (which constitute the vast majority of the market share at this point) would have it.

Comment: After a little looking, I see why. Droids already have orientation sensors, and considering the SensorManager package has been around since API level 1, they've had them for quite some time (I found it hard to believe that my Eris would have *anything* on the Desire, and I know for a fact the Eris can do orientation detection), kind of reducing the need for a full-on gyro. In my experience, the current sensors work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

For me Elixir was quite helpful. Under sensors tab it lists all the ones available on the device. By pressing teh play button, you can see the actual values the sensor receives. Great for getting the idea how the specific sensor works.

If you want to get information on the device's physical orientation, you can use 4 different sensors:

- Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER (0, 0, 9.8)
- Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY (0, 0, 9.8)
- Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION (x, 0, 0)
- Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR (x, 0, 0)

Values in braces denote value of the values[] in SensoreEvent when device is facing the sky. x notes nonspecific value...

The values returned to your SensorEventListener impl are detailed here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Gyroscope sensor u can also accelerometer sensor to find orientation but it returns m/s^2 in x,y,z direction.